# Integrate third party SDK into Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

How can I integrate a third party SDK into my Cordova App.

I cannot find any official documentation, only out of date (~2yo) discussions.

Thanks

Comment: There are various approaches depending if the native SDK is published (iOS => Cocoapods/Android => Maven) or is a local file (Android => .jar/aar/iOS => .framework). The best thing is to look at existing plugins to see how they do it, such as [FabricPlugin](https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin) for iOS local .framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DaveAlden. The Android SDK is .aar library and the iOS SDK is an archive (.a extension). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android, you need to reference the `.aar` in `plugin.xml`, for example:

```
<platform name="android">
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/my-sdk.aar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />
```

You also need to create a Gradle config file which references it, for example `src/android/libs/my-sdk.gradle` should contain:

```
repositories{
    jcenter()
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'my-sdk', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

And place a reference to the Gradle file in `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <framework src="src/android/libs/my-sdk.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

For iOS, you need to import the compiled static library in `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <source-file src="src/ios/libs/libMySDK.a" framework="true" />
```

You then need to include top-level header file(s) for your library in your plugin and reference them from `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <header-file src="src/ios/Headers/MySDK.h"/>
```

You can use other existing plugins as working examples, such as  [movintracks/cordova-plugin](https://github.com/movintracks/cordova-plugin) which uses `.aar` for an Android library and `.a` for iOS.

Comment: Hey @DaveAlden, thanks for your help!
I am trying to build the project but when I build through Cordova I get an error saying `"Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find :MyThirdPartySDK:."`. I have this in my gradle file: `dependencies { compile(name:'MyThirdPartySDK', ext:'aar') }`. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: It was an easy one. Solved changing `dirs` to 'src/android/libs' (now matches the `target-dir` specified in the plugin.xml file)